# Python scripts flash and fail on doubleclick

Tags: python, doubleclick

When I try to run any Python script by double-clicking it on my desktop or in Caja, a terminal window comes up for a split second (so execution does start) and then disappears, without the script running. All my scripts start with the *#!/usr/bin/env python3* shebang line and Python 3 is installed. I can execute them with no problems from a Python or IPython session. What could be preventing them from running on doubleclick?

Comment: Probably it executes and finishes so fast that you can not see it. You could e.g. add a simple `input()` line at the end of your script so that it waits for the ENTER key to be pressed before terminating.

Comment: No, the things that the scripts are meant to do are not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The Python files contained Windows line endings ("\r\n") instead of Unix ones ("\n"). IPython was able to run them anyway but env was not, reading the shebang line as calling "python3\r". Changing the line endings to Unix style solved it. Many text editors have a command to do this, for example Geany has various options in *Document* / *Set Line Endings*.

Comment: You can also use `dos2unix` to fix the line endings.